Heater/AC trips an entirely different breaker when it kicks on
SOLVED
*Edit: Thanks to the comments, I went back and checked all of the neutral wires. When I pulled all of the outlets back out (but still wired), the breaker stayed on. Put them all back and it tripped again. Tried one by one, and the second outlet ground wire was barely touching the stripped part of a neutral. I readjusted the wires so they weren’t touching and it all seems to be working. Thank you all again!
I will try to be as detailed as possible, but the tldr; is that I have a heater/ac unit in the attic on a 15-amp tandem breaker and when the ac turns on it trips the 15-amp cafi breaker above it.

So, I am not an electrician. I work at Home Depot, but no former electricians on staff. I have been trying to find an electrician off and on for about 2 years to take care of a couple of other issues, but am struggling to have anyone call back for smaller residential projects (Mobile, AL).
I have been renovating our office and have replaced 2 light switches, and 5 outlets. 4 outlets in the room are attached to the 15-amp cafi breaker in position 4, and 1 in the closet is on the lower 15-amp tandem switch in position 7 (along with 2 gfci outlets in the master bath). During replacement, not having many electrical tools, I was testing whether the outlets were hot by plugging in a fan and turning it on. Initially all 5 outlets seemed to be off when breaker 4 was switched off, but the closet outlet was live when I removed the live wire, sparked, and tripped its breaker. I went and grabbed a voltage tester and pulled out a gfci outlet tester and made sure power was cut off before replacing the outlet.
Since then, every time the ac unit kicks on, it trips the breaker in position 4. The ac unit is attached to the upper tandem switch in position 6. We have since found out that breaker 4 also feeds the outlets in our front room. Our house is on a ‘rule of six’ setup with 3 breakers outside by the meter box (2 to the house and 1 to the hvac unit on the other side of the house).

I have now tested all of the outlets in both rooms with the tester tool to verify they all work and are wired correctly while the heater/ac breaker is off. I have replaced the breakers in positions 4 and 6, made sure all of the ground wires are tight, and all wires to the breakers are tight. Both boxes are Square D QO series, and all breakers appear to be QOT breakers.
The only other electrical work I have done in the house was switch out regular 15-amp outlets in the master bath with 15-amp gfci outlets for safety and to let my wife use a blow dryer in there. This was almost a year ago and I haven’t had any problems since.
So my question is: why would the attic ac unit on breaker 6 be tripping breaker 4, and is there anything I can do to fix it? I am going to start reaching out to some electricians again and hope for better luck, but I’m hoping it’s not a quick fix that I am just ignorant of.
You all have been very helpful in explaining concepts and solutions in other threads, so I want to thank you all in advance.

Can you post your update as an answer please? I'll upvote it for you if you do :)

Run the diagnostics
First, white button Square D breakers have a procedure for detecting the reason for the fault.  This is called "Time Saver Diagnostics" (hey, they exhausted their Truth in Advertising when they called their other panel HomeLine).  You will need a stopwatch or phone so you can distinguish the amount of time.   But then you will know whether it is an overload, GFCI or AFCI trip.
About AFCI
The answer I'm expecting is "AFCI trip". Why is that? Because AFCIs operate by "listening" for the "sound" of arcing. You know that sound if you've ever dealt with a faulty headphone cable or plugged speakers into an amplifier with the power turned on.
Because of the way electrical signals propagate, AFCIs can hear arcing on the LINE side (outside) their zone of protection, if the arcing is strong enough.
So there's a fair probability that you have an arcing fault on the A/C circuit which only arcs during the startup surge.  It will eventually get worse, so, cheaper to find it today.
Torque screwdriver!
NEC 110.3(B) has always required a torque screwdriver to be used when tightening terminals, including the small stuff.  This was not respected, so NEC 110.14(D) was added to drive the point home.
However, if a terminal is arcing, it is not enough to torque it after the fact. You'll just be grinding soot and ash into soot and ash. The terminal must be pulled apart, visually inspected, cleaned up if needed, and put back together and retorqued. Don't cut the squeezed wire off for a fresh wire, unless the wire is very gored up and beyond fixing. Twist stranded conductors tight so they fit well.
Wrong breakers
This isn't a problem for QO panels since the shape is unique, but since you're in the trade, let's go there.
Customer has a BR panel, should they use Square D Homeline? NOOOOO! See NEC 110.3(B), panel labeling, and heck - contact Eaton and Square D corporate and ask them!  The bus stab designs are slightly different, and one is not the right shape for the other.  It makes edge contact instead of surface contact, and that causes arcing.
UL absolutely will approve breakers for competitor panels. These breakers are UL-Classified with a special UL logo, and consist of Eaton Type >>CL<< for most 1" panels... and for Square D "QO" panels, Eaton CHQ and Siemens QD.  But that's it. No other crossovers.
If it was technically possible to get Siemens QP approved for everybody else's panel, believe me Siemens would do it. They cant'. It's not safe.

SOLVED
*Edit: Thanks to the comments, I went back and checked all of the neutral wires. When I pulled all of the outlets back out (but still wired), the breaker stayed on. Put them all back and it tripped again. Tried one by one, and the second outlet ground wire was barely touching the stripped part of a neutral. I readjusted the wires so they weren’t touching and it all seems to be working. Thank you all again!

A few possibilities:

There might be a neutral fault. Check the voltage on a few outlets that have something running, such as lamp (which you can carry from outlet-to-outlet). Make this test with the AC and again with it off. If the voltage on some outlets is much above 120 VAC, or much below 120 VAC, there is an issue with the neutral wire. An electrician must fix that as soon as possible, because it is a serious safety hazard.
You state you've been renovating. In rewiring, circuits became cross-wired. An electrician must fix that as soon as possible, because it is also a serious safety hazard.
GFCI breakers can trip when there is a power surge in a nearby circuit. However, from the appearance of those breakers, I do not think those involved are GFCI's.

